# Transient behaviour of capacitor discharge

Tags: transient

As far as my understanding, I think of a decaying exponential curve of a current in the case of a capacitor discharging. But sometimes (not sure on this), it shoes a damping waveform -- there are some positive peaks and negative peaks. What is the explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: How are you observing this? Real world behaviour has real world parasitics like inductance capacitance and resistance. As well, the measurement technique will affect what is observed.

Comment: I think this spread of 3 decade values shows a good variation  https://tinyurl.com/yzkqmxg4

Answer (score 3):

With a sufficiently large series resistance, you would get exponential decay, as expected. With a small series resistance, the inductance of the wires and of the capacitor itself forms a resonant circuit, creating a damped waveform. This is the basis of a [spark-gap transmitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark-gap_transmitter).

Also note there are non-linear effects, such as the spark being "quenched" as the voltage and current drop.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. I want to ask another thing here. How can you relate corresponding waveform to load mismatch scenrios. I mean if the load impedence is smaller than the main circuit, do we get a underdamped response. What happens when there is exact load match. And what happens when load impedence is greater than the main circuit. (Main circuit includes a capacitor discharge through a switch)

Comment: Good question -- see https://www.giangrandi.ch/electronics/ringdownq/ringdownq.shtml for example. BTW, it depends what you measure in the waveform, i.e., *current* or *voltage*, if the load has overriding inductive or capacitive mismatch (above and below resonance).

Comment: I am talking about current here. I am not getting it. So far i had studied that there should be a exponentially decaying curve but why am i getting underdamped waveform